# Check-Out not functioning: Documents are Checked-In when moving from Onedrive and Other Libraries

Tags: sharepoint-online, file-upload, check-out, power-automate, check-in

When creating a new document within our respective Sites, the items are checked-out by default. This is standard expected behaviour.

However, we have stumbled across a problem where an item is Checked-In on a Library if it is coming from a Library/Source(Onedrive) in which it is checked-in (published).

What we are finding is that our Users are importing stuff in to Sharepoint but aren't filling in mandatory fields that we need them to fill in! So there is a lot of stuff on our Sharepoint that isn't filled in as well as we'd like!

Asides from a Flow, is there anything else we could do to ensure that this doesn't keep happening? We cannot change User behaviour!

Essentially, we just need to ensure items are kept in a Draft state until the User has checked the item in, Manually, which requires they enter in mandatory fields.

As you can see below, this Document is checked-in, but there are still items (mandatory) that are missing! Which isn't physically possible if you are creating a new document.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new document in the library, the document will default to the check-out state.

When you move a document from one library to another library, the document will keep the check-in state and versions in the move process, it's by design.

I don't think it's possible to make the document in check-in state become check-out when it is moved to another library.

Comment: this is very problematic for data governance as it means that data without mandatory columns is added to SPO without users being forced to ammend. I even tried workflows to see if I could get this to trigger a forced check-out but no luck.

Comment: If the issue is urgent, you could open a ticket with Microsoft for further help.